# NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'Data parameter is nil'

Tags: ios

I've looked at other questions similar to my problem but none of them seemed to work.

The error I'm getting from my debugger is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil''

And here is my code

```
{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"A valid URL"];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

            jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
            NSLog(@"NSJSONSerialization is executed");

            schoolArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"NSMutableArray is executed");


            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.count; i++) {
                NSString *sName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"SchoolNameID"];
                NSString *sLink = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"SchoolPHPLink"];
                NSString *sImage = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"SchoolImage"];
                NSString *sMascot = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"SchoolMascot"];
                [schoolArray addObject:[[Schools alloc] initWithSchoolName:sName andSchoolLink:sLink andschoolImage:sImage andSchoolMascot:sMascot]];

            }
            [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    }
```

I know the the problem is something about the `jsonArray` but
this code used to actually work. After it is working and after publishing it to the App Store, I stored this file away on Google Drive and a few weeks later after opening the file again and just running it without touching any of the code, I get this error. I am stomped and I am very new to debugging.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: After creating the URL, print its value to see if it was initialized correctly.  `NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);`

Comment: @PhillipMills Okay, I've done that and it does print the correct URL.

Comment: But, I assume, if you print `data` after the next assignment, it's `nil`?  There's a comment in the docs that says, "If you need to know the reason for failure, use dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:".  You might try that and see if the error says anything useful.

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia He's saying to replace the call to `dataWithContentsOfURL` with a call to `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`. Pass in an `NSError` for the last parameter. When `data` comes back `nil`, log `error` to see why it is failing.

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia or at least, try to add the NSLog after the NSData *data like this... NSLog(@"%@", data) to see if it's nil or not? Are you running the code for iOS9? the valid url has to be https and support ATS (App Transport Security) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html

Comment: @thanyaj I used the NSLog error and i got a null. What does that imply? And I am running it on iOS 9 and using an http url instead of https. I tried with an https link but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am such a dumbass. Okay I got to give credit to @thanyaj because he lead me to the right track.

So as it turns out, for iOS 9 I cannot use an HTTP link but instead I need to use an HTTPS url because for some reason it doesn't allow it anymore.

But anyways, to fix that is by going to the info.plist file and giving it permission to use HTTP links.

I added `NSAppTransportSecurity Boolean YES` and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. click on your project info.plist
2. click on + sign  Add App Transport Security
3. then you see > sign  click on  this Add Again click on + button.
4. Now Add Allow library loads and click yes on right side.
5. Now run your App error Solved Enjoy.

Comment: library loads??? what is it??? do you mean `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`??? anyway this does not work